# react native picker is not showing in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to add picker in react native android but it does not showing in android. I map my location date to picker item but i did'nt see picker in screen.

```html
<Picker selectedValue={this.state.location}>
  <Picker.Item label="Location 1" value="1" /> 
  <Picker.Item label="Location 2" value="2" />
  <Picker.Item label="Location 3" value="3" />
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set your `onValueChange` method

```
<Picker
    style={{width: 100}} 
    selectedValue={this.state.location}
    onValueChange={(loc) => this.setState({location: loc})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Location 1" value="1" /> 
  <Picker.Item label="Location 2" value="2" />
  <Picker.Item label="Location 3" value="3" />
</Picker>
```

Comment: but i unable to see picker that is what my problem it is hidden in state. so please tell me how to make it visible.

Comment: I don't have an example running locally. I'm trying to get an example running at https://rnplay.org/apps/X0fPdA but I can't get it to execute. You might need to set the `{width: 100}` as demonstrated in the [UIExplorer Example for Picker](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/PickerAndroidExample.js)

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've updated my answer to include the style attribute. Thx

Comment: This worked for me too. Funny it was working for me without setting width when embedded within a modal.

Comment: Similarly, inside a flexbox, I set the Picker's style to `{flex: 1}` to make it work.

Comment: For me I don't get the Picker label on the screen

Answer (score 19):

For me, it was a "alignItems: 'center'," on the parent view component.

I would comment out all/each style of your styles.container

Comment: This was my issue as well.

Answer (score 16):

Are you giving it width and height?
That was my problem

Comment: turns out it need width and height.. yet another stupidity in react native

Comment: also make the width and height BIGGER if its not showing up. I had height: 50 and I couldn't see it until I made height 150!

Answer (score 7):

picker doesn't appear on screen if it doesn't have style with height,weight or flex property

```
<Picker

  style={{flex:1}} >
  <Picker.Item label="Location 1" value="1" /> 
  <Picker.Item label="Location 2" value="2" />
  <Picker.Item label="Location 3" value="3" />

</Picker>
```

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me too by assigning a width to the [Picker](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html) specifically.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a common thing, but this may help someone. I was using the JSON object key loop, but in react native we should use mapping.

*Was using another JSON file to get my array.

```
import Cities from '../my-project-path/Cities.json';
```

The way I tried looping (Not working)

```
let Locations = Object.keys(Cities).forEach(function (key){
    return <Picker.Item key={key} value={key} label={key} />
});
```

Then I used map (Worked for me)

```
let Locations = Object.keys(Cities).map(function (key) {
    return <Picker.Item key={key} value={key} label={key} />
});
```

My component

```
<Picker selectedValue={this.state.District}>
    {Districts}
</Picker>
```