# React native picker not showing on android

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use the Picker component and it shows perfectly fine in iOS but nothing in Android. I've checked the comments on [react native picker is not showing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830815/react-native-picker-is-not-showing-in-android) however setting the `{width: 100}` and `{flex: 1}` doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Update: The Picker is there, works when I tap on the area it's on, just not visible.

I'm using Expo to run the test builds on my iphone and android. No problem on iphone. Just android... Galaxy S8 v7.0 Nougat

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Picker,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state = {
            selectedValue: 'Orange'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Picker
                    style={styles.picker}
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
                    onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({selectedValue: value})}}
                    itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}
                >
                    <Picker.Item label="Apple" value="Apple" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Orange" value="Orange" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Banana" value="Banana" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Kiwi" value="Kiwi" />
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    picker: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    pickerItem: {
        color: '#333333'
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem, I exported the module and imported it in my main `app.js` file and in there I wrapped the module in a container with `alignItems: 'center'`. Apparently this causes the picker to not show. See this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6110

Answer (score 11):

Try To add height and width for Picker. Try Following

```
<Picker
    style={{height:30, width:100}}
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
    onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({selectedValue: value})}}
    itemStyle={styles.pickerItem}>
    <Picker.Item label="Apple" value="Apple" />
    <Picker.Item label="Orange" value="Orange" />
    <Picker.Item label="Banana" value="Banana" />
    <Picker.Item label="Kiwi" value="Kiwi" />
</Picker>
```

Comment: hi, thank you, but doesn't seem to show anything. I've also tried changing the flex, create a `<View></View>` wrapper with and without flex... lol nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and the cause was that I had set `alignItems: 'center'` to the parent view. This is what I wanted though so I didn't remove it. Instead I solved it by giving the picker a width of 100%.

```
<View style={{alignItems: "center"}}>
    <Picker style={{width:"100%"}} mode="dropdown">
        <Picker.Item />
    </Picker>
</View>
```